# JPA issue: trouble with persisting an association class that has an EmbeddedId composite key

Tags: jpa

I'm quite new to learning JPA and looking to get some insight on the following: I'm having trouble persisting rows of an association class into its respective table using JPA.

The association class 'movie_showings' is a 1-to-many with 'movies' on one side and 1-to-many with 'theaters' on the other side. As you can imagine, there is a composite primary key composed of the foreign keys from the latter two classes. I chose to implement that using an Embeddable class, 'movie_showings_pk'.

At this point, instantiating an object of the association class, passing it a movie and a theater to construct a PK is not an issue. Calling the functions to associate the 'movie_showing' instance to 'theaters' and 'movies' respectively is not an issue. However, when I go to PERSIST the 'movie_showings' instance in the database using the entityManager, I get a constraint violation exception that I don't quite understand:

**Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'MOVIES_MID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO movie_showings (DATEOFLASTSHOW, OPENINGDATE, MOVIE, THEATER, MOVIE_MID, THEATER_TID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(PK => MOVIE ID > 3 THEATER ID > 1  Opening Date: Jan-15-2020)**

Here is the function definition I use to test this out:

```
   private void loadInitialMovieShowings ()
   {
      System.out.println ("LOADING movie_showings...");

      List <Movie> allMovies = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Movie.FIND_ALL, Movie.class).getResultList();
      List <Theater> allTheaters = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Theater.FIND_ALL, Theater.class).getResultList();

      Theater spectrum = null;
      for (Theater theater : allTheaters)
         if (theater.getName().contains("Irvine Spectrum"))
            spectrum = new Theater (theater);

      List <Movie> allStarWars = new ArrayList<>();

      for (Movie movie : allMovies)
         if (movie.getTitle().contains("Star Wars"))
            allStarWars.add(movie);

      for (Movie movie : allStarWars)
      {
         MovieShowing temp = new MovieShowing (movie, spectrum,
                 new GregorianCalendar(2020, 00, 15),
                 new GregorianCalendar(2020, 04, 04));

         movie.addMovieShowing(temp);
         spectrum.addMovieShowing(temp);

         entityManager.persist (temp);
      }
   }
```

This is (part of) the association class:

```
public class MovieShowing 
{
    // QUERY STRING(S)
    public static final String FIND_ALL_ID = "MovieShowing.FIND_ALL_ID";
    public static final String FIND_ALL_INFO = "MovieShowing.FIND_ALL_INFO";

    @EmbeddedId
    private Movie_Showings_PK ms_id;

    @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
    private GregorianCalendar openingDate;

    @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
    private GregorianCalendar dateOfLastShow;

    // ASSOCIATION(S)
    @ManyToOne
    private Theater theater;

    @ManyToOne 
    private Movie movie;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public MovieShowing () { }
    public MovieShowing (Movie movie, Theater theater, GregorianCalendar opening, GregorianCalendar closing)
    {
        ms_id = new Movie_Showings_PK(movie, theater);

        setMovie(movie);
        setTheater(theater);
        setOpeningDate(opening);
        setDateOfLastShow(closing);
    }

    ...
```

This is the Embeddedable class:

```
public class Movie_Showings_PK
{
    @Basic
    private Long theater;

    @Basic
    private Long movie;

    // CONSTRUCTORS
    public Movie_Showings_PK () {}
    public Movie_Showings_PK (Movie movie, Theater theater)
    {
        this.movie = movie.getMID ();
        this.theater = theater.getTID ();
    }
    ...
```

I'm sure the answer is right in my face but I've been scratching my head for a couple days trying to figure it out... Thanks for any insight, all!

Answer (score 0):

AH. I was an idiot. Inside my 'Movie' class, I had mistakenly put a separate @ManyToMany association with 'Theater' in a previous attempt to link up these two tables. After removing it, everything worked out fine. Chalk this one up to growing pains..